# Masking before Conv1D in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to mask zeros before conv1D layer, but this is not supported do you have a solution for this problem.

Here's a piece of my code :

```py
# Defining the neural network architecture. This contains five TDNN layers, statistics layer, two fully connected layers followed by the softmax output.

input_shape_data=(1865,20)

main_input = Input(shape=input_shape_data, dtype='float', name='main_input')

u = Masking(mask_value=0.)(main_input)

x1 = Conv1D(512, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same',dilation_rate=1,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros')(u)
x1 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think that TimeDistributed Layer does this, but I m not sure

Comment: got any solution for this?